# linq query analogous to sql Not In, In clause

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I want the linq query analogous to sql query mentioned below

***select HTId,HTN from tblHTMaster where HTId in (
select HTId from tblUHTs 
where UId='F7ECFB41-177F-4408-B856-A4F669FAA714')***

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try by yourself before posting here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from s in db.tblMaster
let t= from u in db.tblUHTs
   where u.UId='F7ECFB41-177F-4408-B856-A4F669FAA714'
   select u.HTId
where t.Contains(s.HTId)
select new {s.HTId, s.HTN}
```

Comment: By answering this you only encourage people to post crappy questions. They seem to think that SO is a code conversion service.